# Robocopy: log output doesn't explain what happened to the total=436 dirs?

Tags: robocopy

```
             Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
Dirs :       436         0        11         0         0         3
```

Can you explain that output of robocopy? I've used the `/MIR` parameter. What happened to my total = 436 dirs?